# using monit to control node.js pm2 response time

Tags: node.js, monit

I want to use `monit` for ability to reload [pm2](https://github.com/unitech/pm2) `node.js` site if response is longer than 2 seconds.

This is my monit config `/etc/monit/monitrc`:

```
check process pm2 with pidfile "/root/.pm2/pids/siteName9000.pid" 
        start program = "/usr/local/bin/pm2 start ~/pathToNodeApp/9000/app.js --name siteName9000" 
        stop program  = "/usr/local/bin/pm2 stop siteName9000" 
        if failed port 9000 protocol HTTP 
            request / 
            with timeout 2 seconds 
            then restart
```

Then in console I run:

```
# monit restart pm2
```

Then in console I run:

```
# monit -d 10 -c /etc/monit/monitrc
```

to make this checking every 10 seconds.

Then in monit log `/var/log/monit.log` I see:

```
[MSK May 18 06:57:05] info     : 'pm2' restart on user request
[MSK May 18 06:57:05] info     : monit daemon with PID 22480 awakened
[MSK May 18 06:57:05] info     : Awakened by User defined signal 1
[MSK May 18 06:57:05] info     : 'pm2' trying to restart
[MSK May 18 06:57:05] info     : 'pm2' start: /usr/local/bin/pm2
[MSK May 18 06:57:36] error    : 'pm2' failed to start
[MSK May 18 06:57:36] info     : 'pm2' restart action done
[MSK May 18 06:58:27] info     : Awakened by User defined signal 1
[MSK May 18 06:58:27] error    : 'pm2' process is not running
[MSK May 18 06:58:27] info     : 'pm2' trying to restart
[MSK May 18 06:58:27] info     : 'pm2' start: /usr/local/bin/pm2
[MSK May 18 06:58:27] info     : monit daemon with PID 22480 awakened
[MSK May 18 06:58:58] error    : 'pm2' failed to start
[MSK May 18 07:00:58] error    : 'pm2' process is not running
[MSK May 18 07:00:58] info     : 'pm2' trying to restart
[MSK May 18 07:00:58] info     : 'pm2' start: /usr/local/bin/pm2
```

So my monit config not working.

Comment: I think your check interval is too small. What happens at 30 seconds? 60 seconds?

Comment: changed 10 seconds to 60: the same result

Comment: In `start program` directive, what happens if you replace `~` by `/full/path/to/pathToNodeApp/9000/app.js........` ?